# pandas convert object column to string type

Tags: python, string, pandas, dtype

I don't understand the following strange conversion behavior in pandas:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x', 'y'], 'b': ['s', 't']})
s = d['a'].astype('|S1')
print(s.dtypes)
d['a'] = s
print(d.dtypes)
print(s.dtypes)
print(d.astype('|S1').dtypes)
```

produced the output:

```
|S1
a    object
b    object
dtype: object
|S1
a    |S1
b    |S1
dtype: object
```

When I convert a column as a `pd.Series` it gets converted, but when put back into the `DataFrame`, it reverts back to `Object`. But the whole 'DataFrame` can be converted. What gives?

I have been scouring the documentation to find some reference to this behavior, but didn't find any clue.

Just for completeness, here is an abbreviated version:

```
python           : 3.7.3.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Windows
OS-release       : 10
machine          : AMD64
processor        : Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel

pandas           : 0.25.1
numpy            : 1.17.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps if I understand the issue:

Try overwriting the column instead of assigning it to s

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':['x', 'y'], 'b': ['s', 't']})
d['a'] = d['a'].astype('|S1')
```

I have always been accustomed to using .astype(str), but not sure of your specific situation.

Comment: If you had tried that code you would have seen that it does not work. Similarly, `d['a'] = d['a'].astype(str)` does not do anything different.

Comment: I tried that code, or else would not have posted. As stated, maybe not understanding the question. Apologies

Comment: Apologies for jumping to conclusions, but when I did it, `d.dtypes` only had `object` types and not `str` or `|S1`.

Comment: I was under the impression that pandas stores str as object. All of my string formats come out dtype object. What are you trying to do with the string that object dtype does not suffice? Also have you tried astype('str') in addition to str without quotes?

Comment: If you note, when you convert the entire dataframe to `|S1`, then the dtypes are not `object`s, but are `|S1`. So it is possible to have an `|S1` dtype in a dataframe column. This does not work for `str` which is always an object. As to why, an `|S1` is a single byte and takes much less space. I have a huge dataframe.

Comment: I see... Have you checked around to see if |S1 is even available to return as a value via .dtypes?

Comment: As noted in the post, when you convert the whole dataframe, then the dtype `|S1` shows up (look at the last dtype printout).